# My jquery script is adding white space to html5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, whitespace

I'm using this jquery snippet to make sure my html5 background video stays centred, full-screen and properly aligned.
`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $win = $(window),
    $video = $('#full-video'),
    $videoWrapper = $video.parent();

function scaleVideo() {
    var isWider = ( $video.width() > $videoWrapper.width() ) ? true : false,
        isTaller = ( $video.height() > $win.height() ) ? true : false,
        widthDifference = $video.width() - $videoWrapper.width(),
        heightDifference = $video.height() - $videoWrapper.height();

    ( isWider ) ? $video.css('left',-parseInt(widthDifference / 2)) : $video.css('left', '0');
    ( isTaller ) ? $video.css('top', -parseInt(heightDifference / 2)) : $video.css('top', '0');
}

scaleVideo();
$win.resize(function() {
    scaleVideo();
});
});
```

`

At first it wasn't doing anything at all so I added the $(document).ready(function() around it. Now it works except for some reason when I reload the page there is white space (~20px) that appears on the right side of the video. If I adjust the size of the browser window at all it disappears but reappears again if I reload/refresh the page.

here's a link to it in action: http://wabi-sabi.cc

This is the html:

`<body>
    <div class="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="full-video-wrapper">
            <video id="full-video" muted preload autoplay loop>
                <source src="videos/wabisabiwebvideo.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="videos/wabisabiwebvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>`

And here's the css:

```
.slide-wrapper {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.full-video-wrapper {
background: white;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
overflow: hidden;
}

#full-video {
display: block;
position: absolute;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your html? What is the html tag of `#full-video`?

Comment: sorry abmitchell, i posted it prematurely, i've added the html and css

Comment: Are you sure that's everything? I'm not getting any white space. Is this hosted on a site somewhere I could look at?

Comment: I might have neglected something but I have made some changes since I put this up. The issue is still the same, however, I'll put it up here for now: http://www.evinulrichpohl.com/wabisabitest/

Comment: I just noticed the white space is even more massive in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out. It was quite simple, really, I am just very new to Javascript

Instead of using
`$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

I used `window.onload = function() { ... }`

I was making the script jump the gun before the page had loaded properly.
Now I have a great background video that stays centred and aligned as the window is resized!

Hopefully someone else learning javascript can learn from this as well.